# Flutter: Set button height to fill container

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to make my button to fill my container. 
[image]

But as you can see from the picture above, the button (red) on the left clearly did not fill the entire container(green). I can solve this by adding height to MaterialButton, but IMHO this is not the best solution, because device's height might differ. Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text("Button A"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text("Button B"),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply Add - `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,`  in `MaterialButton`

```
Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,  // Add this
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text("Button A"),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: MaterialButton(
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, // Add this
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text("Button B"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You may can try

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 48,
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text("Button A"),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 48,
                child: MaterialButton(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text("Button B"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```